# Different Data Types in Neo4j Cypher Query language

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, cql, datamodel

I want to know how can we define different data types in CQL.
For example, in SQL we have lots of different data types like `int`, `float`, `decimal` or variable character.

But in CQL, when we are creating the nodes we do not define its data type, we just write: Create (a: User{UserName:'Jack', Age:23})

What is the data type for the `Age` Property? Is it integer? Float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cypher language provides basic support for integer, float, string, byte[], boolean and others.

You can [read the docs here on cypher typing](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/values/).

Neo4j 3.4 which will be out fairly soon will have support for geospatial and temporal types.  As of this writing (3.3.4 latest) this isn't yet supported in the stable version.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a node by creating it within (). Similarly, you define a relationship within []. These symbols explicitly represent these data types which is why they have been required since one of the 2.x versions.